# Tkinter Scrollbar X in desired Tab

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Im working with tabs in a tkinter project, but I got little problem I want use both scroollbars (x and y axis) Im creating canvas for each tab I want to use them, Y axis works,X axis works but the positing is weird its small like the pic attached, tried many ways but cant achieve to looks like "fill=X" like Y axis, any ideas ples, tried so many options, thanks in advance

```
from tkinter import LEFT, font
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title('Title')
root.state('zoomed')

addtab=ttk.Notebook(root)
firsttab=tk.Frame(addtab)
secondtab=tk.Frame(addtab)
thirdtab=tk.Frame(addtab)
fourthtab=tk.Frame(addtab)
addtab.add(firsttab,text="Summary Input files")
addtab.add(secondtab, text="Single Date")
addtab.add(thirdtab, text="Two Date")
addtab.add(fourthtab, text="Three Date")
addtab.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

my_canvas=tk.Canvas(secondtab)
#my_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
my_scrollbarx=tk.Scrollbar(secondtab,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=my_canvas.xview)
my_scrollbarx.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)
my_scrollbary=tk.Scrollbar(secondtab,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbary.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
my_canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=my_scrollbarx.set,yscrollcommand=my_scrollbary.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
root1_2=tk.Frame(my_canvas)
my_canvas.create_window((0,0),window=root1_2,anchor="nw")
frame1_1=tk.Frame(root1_2)
frame1_1.pack(anchor='w')
label1=tk.Label(frame1_1,text='Results',fg='red',font=("Arial", 20))
label1.pack()

my_canvas1=tk.Canvas(fourthtab)
my_canvas1.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
my_scrollbarx1=tk.Scrollbar(fourthtab,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,command=my_canvas1.xview)
my_scrollbarx1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)
my_scrollbary1=tk.Scrollbar(fourthtab,orient=tk.VERTICAL,command=my_canvas1.yview)
my_scrollbary1.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
my_canvas1.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbary1.set, xscrollcommand=my_scrollbarx1.set)
my_canvas1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:my_canvas1.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas1.bbox("all")))
root1_21=tk.Frame(my_canvas1)
my_canvas1.create_window((0,0),window=root1_21,anchor="nw")
frame1_11=tk.Frame(root1_21)
frame1_11.pack(anchor='w')
label11=tk.Label(frame1_11,text='Results2',fg='red',font=("Arial", 20))
label11.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: thanks to @acw1668 now its working.
[image]

Comment: The order of packing matters.  Pack the bottom scrollbar first.  It is more easier if `.grid()` is used instead of `.pack()`.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks for answering, but packing X first isnt working, just for this project  I need to use pack because there are a lot of more tabs alredy created in main project

Comment: Packing the bottom scrollbar first works for me.  If there are only the canvas and the two scrollbars inside the tab, it is ok to use `.grid()` instead of `.pack()`.

Comment: Edited question with suggestion and added a picture, didnt fill X axis, unfortunatly there a lot of widgets inside canvas @acw1668

Comment: If the scrollbars and canvas are the only thing in a frame, it's best to use `grid`. You can safely do so and still use `pack` in other places in your code. You can use pack, but that typically results in scrollbars that don't align the way most scrollbars do.

Comment: You need to pack the bottom scrollbar first, then the right scrollbar and the canvas.

Comment: Today I learned  that the order of packing matters, doing X first, Y second and canvas finally works, thanks  @acw1668

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for suggestion ill do that in future projects